# d3 tree - How to append buttons/templates on circles?

Tags: html, templates, d3.js, tree, append

I am working with this [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).

My question is how to create/append html elements in a circle. That is just the basic idea. If there are any better solutions for it i would appreciate if you tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use HTML elements in SVG, you need to use the [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), which allows you to embed HTML elements. Here is a D3 [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037) that does that. This allows you to put arbitrary content inside the circles, whose radius you will have to adjust accordingly to accommodate the content.

Answer (score 0):

Each node contains a circle and text

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(360,165.2173913043478)">
     <circle r="4.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
     <text x="-10" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;">interpolate</text>
</g>
```

modify the r attribute in circle to get a bigger one and the x parameter in text to set the text into the circle, like that:

```
<circle r="28.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<text x="24" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;">interpolate</text>
```

;)

Comment: hey you got me wrong. the text is no problem. i want to include buttons(html) and stuff. Look at Lars Kotthoffs answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var menu = {
      "nodes": [
            {id: 0, "x": 300, "y": 250, "url": "newProject()", "text": "New Project", "bcolor": "#000099", "color": "white", "dx":-40},
            {id: 1, "x": 300, "y": 10, "url": "search('project')", "text": "Project", "bcolor": "#FF9900", "color": "black", "dx":-30},
            {id: 2, "x": 10, "y": 400, "url": "search('customer')","text": "Customer", "bcolor": "#FF9900", "color": "black", "dx":-40},
            {id: 3, "x": 600, "y": 400, "url": "search('unit')","text": "Unit Title", "bcolor": "#FF9900", "color": "black", "dx":-30}]};

var width = 900, height = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#projectMenu").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var w = 200, h = 100;
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(menu.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node");

node.append("rect")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x;})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y;})
            .attr("rx", 10)
            .attr("ry", 10)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {return d.bcolor;});
```

**/* THIS is for YOU ;) */**

```
var fo = node.append("foreignObject")
                .attr("width",w)
                .attr("height",h)
                .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x;})
                .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y;})
```

**// IMPORTANT : prefix with namespace to allow D3 rendering following HTML code**

```
            .append("xhtml:body") 
                .attr("class", "projectMenu")
            .append("div");

var table = fo.append("table")
    .attr("class", "projectMenu");

table.append("tr").append("td")
    .append("p")
    .attr("class", "projectMenu")
    .text(function(d) {return d.text;});

table.append("tr").append("td")
    .append("input")
    .attr("name", "byName")
    .attr("class", "input");
```

**// AND this too ... (you can replace 'ng-click' by onclick, I'm using AngularJs)**

```
table.append("tr").append("td")
    .append("button")
    .attr("ng-click", function(d){return d.url;})
    .text("Search");
```